# Strange Vue.js behaviour using external constants

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm quite new to Vue.js so it may be quite typical but as for me it's strange - 
I'm using Iview and have parent component like

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    Medics()
    Managers()
</template>
```

and two similar child components

**Medics**

```
<template lang="pug">
  ...
    Table(:columns="table.columns", :data="table.data")
  ...
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {},
    data() {
      return {
        table: {
          columns: [],
          data: []
      }
   }
</script>
```

**Managers**

```
<template lang="pug">
  ...
    Table(:columns="table.columns", :data="table.data")
  ...
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {},
    data() {
      return {
        table: {
          columns: [],
          data: []
      }
   }
</script>
```

and it works just fine. 
But if I change `table` **in both components** to some external constants like

```
//constants.js
const CONSTANTS = {
  EMPTY_TABLE: {
    columns: [],
    data: []
  },
  SUCCESSFUL_RESPONSE: {
    result: 'success'
  }
}

module.exports = CONSTANTS
```

(using Vue plugin)

```
// constantPlugin.js
import CONSTANTS from './constants.js'

const Constants = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$getConst = (key) => {
      return CONSTANTS[key]
    }
  }
}

export default Constants


//main.js
import Constants from '../lib/constantsPlugin'
Vue.use(Constants)
```

and then

```
<script>
  import constants from './constants.js'

  export default {
    components: {},
    data() {
      return {
        table: { this.$getConst('EMPTY_TABLE')  }
   }
</script>
```

After that change both tables shows **same** data despite of dividing them to different components (*Medics* and *Managers*).

What am I doing wrong? How it should be done?

EDIT: added Vue plugin but still no luck using it.

Comment: There's only one EMPTY_TABLE.

Comment: @DaveNewton edited

Comment: There's still only one EMPTY_TABLE.  You assigned it to both components, but they are sharing it.  Either make a function that returns the structure of the empty table or maybe do an `Object.assign({}, constants.EMPTY_TABLE)`.

Comment: @PatrickSteele thanks, see edit.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about my function comment.  Make a function that returns a new instance of the object -- not the same object each time: `function getEmptyTable() { return { data: [], columns: [] } };`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. There is a single object called `EMPTY_TABLE`. Every time you refer to `EMPTY_TABLE` you are referring to the same object. If you change it anywhere, all references to it will see the same `EMPTY_TABLE` (because there's only one).

Comment: @DaveNewton ok, I've ended using function like `let request = objectLookup(CONSTANTS, path), //some other function to retrieve property value
        result = {}

      Object
        .keys(request)
        .forEach(key => {
          result[key] = request[key]
        })

      return result` sorry for formating.

Comment: Did you get this working? please post a answer in this case.